# Given that $\tan x=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$, Show that $a_n=0$, for even n

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

Given that $\tan x=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$, Show that $a_n=0$, for even n.

from the series expansions of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, I get that
$\tan x=\frac{x-(x^3/3!)+(x^5/5!)...}{1-(x^2/2!)+(x^4/4!)...}$
But it is not clear how to show that for even $n$, $a_n=0$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\tan$ is an odd function.

Comment: what d you mean by an odd function?

Comment: only odd powers of $x$ in the series expansion are present?

Comment: See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Taylor_Series_Expansion_for_Tangent_Function

Comment: is there a simpler answer, because this question appears as just the introduction to a much larger question

Comment: A function $f$ is odd if $f(-x) = -f(x)$ for all $x$. There are several ways of showing that if $\sum_n a_n x^n$ is an odd function, then $a_n = 0$ for all even $n$.

Comment: ah I see, so converting to $\sin$ and $\cos$ just complicates things, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Assume $g$ is differentiable in some $(-a,a).$ Show that i) if $g$ is an odd function, then $g'$ is even. ii) if $g$ is an even function, then $g'$ is odd. What does this imply about the power series coefficients of an odd function?

Comment: yeah this makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since $\tan 0=0$, we have $a_0=0$.

From
$$\tan x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$
we can differentiate and
$$1+\tan^2x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}$$
But this means that
$$1+\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\right)^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}$$

For $n=2m\ge 2$, we can use induction and assume that $a_{2r}=0$ for $r<m$. Then we have
$$2ma_{2m}=\sum_{j+k=2m-1}2a_ja_k$$
The terms $a_ja_k$ of the RHS are all zero, since $j$ and $k$ have different parity, and both are lesser than $2m$. Thus $a_{2m}=0$.