# Trouble with series question from STEP past paper

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

[image]
I have answered all parts of this question but the last part. By using the identity, $\cot x - \tan x = 2\cot 2x$
$$\frac{1}{x}+(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_nx^n-a_nx^n)=\frac{1}{2x}+\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_n(2x)^n$$

$$(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_nx^n-a_nx^n)=-\frac{1}{2x}+\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_n2^nx^n$$

$$(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}-a_nx^n)=-\frac{1}{2x}+\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(b_n2^nx^n-b_nx^n)$$

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n=\frac{1}{2x}+\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(b_nx^n(1-2^n))$$

I'm almost there with the asnwer, except I don't know what to do with $\frac{1}{2x}$. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365705/given-that-tan-x-sum-i-0-inftya-nxn-show-that-a-n-0-for-even-n

Comment: Better write it in the form $\tan x = \cot x - 2\cot (2x)$.

Comment: But, the point is, you forgot a factor $2$ on the right hand side.

Comment: What is STEP ?.

Comment: an admission exam required for studying maths in some of the top universities in the UK, http://www.admissionstestingservice.org/for-test-takers/step/preparing-for-step/

Comment: I've realized I've left out the factor of $2$ which answers my question. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

You missed a 2 factor on the right in the first equation when you wrote the series.